# Linux Assembly : Does INT 0x80H Stand for it's offset or truly for it's interrupt instruction

Tags: linux, memory, assembly, x86, interrupt

I'm currently learning x86 Linux ASM and stumbled upon Interrupt Vectors.

From what I could find out, it seems that data at 0x0H-0x7FH is reserved for x86 Specific interrupts, where else everything from 0x80H - 0x400H is User definable and usually reserved by the operating system, in this case Linux.

Then however I found out that each interrupt has it's own INT address which is incremented by every Interrupt Vector (after every DWORD of memory) rather than the physical memory address.

My question is if the `INT 0x80` instruction stands for the physical memory offset or if it's simply coincidence and truly stands for the INT address (at mem address 0x200H)

Comment: Linux is a protected mode operating system where interrupts work differently. `int 0x80` is the `0x80` entry in the IDT (interrupt descriptor table). In real mode, the `int 0x80` vector would be at address `0x200` (note that `0x80 * 4` is not `0x320`).

Comment: Thanks for the correction, my HEX skills (especially div and mult) are still doing progress.

Comment: It doesn't have to "stand for" anything.  [The `0x80` constant is encoded into the instruction as described by the instruction reference manual](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/INT%20n:INTO:INT%203.html).  As Jester says, the CPU handles interrupts by checking the IDT in protected / compat / long mode.

Comment: Thanks for linking the manual, that vastly cleared up things for me!